# Disable all controls within div in asp.net 

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Can someone tell me how I can disable all controls within a div?

The div is set to runat="server"

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You probably want to use a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx) control (which renders a `<div>`), have those controls you want disabled contained within it and then set the Panel's `Enabled` property to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for a simple solution - bung it in panel and myPanel.enabled = false simples! :)

Comment: Great simple solution :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since the OP asked how to do this with a DIV with runat="server" I thought I'd add a solution for that:

```
myDiv.Attributes.Add("Disabled", "");
```

That's what a Panel with Enabled = false is rendered as anyway, and requires no change in your code. There is no need for a attribute value (like *True*), since the presence of the attribute itself is enough.

Note: to *enable* your DIV again, you can't just set the *Disabled* attribute to *False*. You have to remove the attribute alltogether:

```
myDiv.Attributes.Remove("Disabled");
```